# Increasing the size of the board (CHESS)

Tags: size, chessboard

In the following document the `\bigskip\makediagrams` option generates an image with the same size as `\smallskip\makediagrams`. Is it possible to make the image bigger?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{texmate}
\title{Título}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Sección}

Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg .

|1. d4 d5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Bf4 c5 \toD{c5} 4.e3 Nc6 5.c3 Nh5! 6.dxc5 Nxf4 7.exf4 e6 8.b4 Qf6 9.Qd2 a5! 10.b5 Nb8! 11.Qe3 Qe7! 12.c4 Qxc5 13.cxd5 Qxe3+ 14.fxe3 exd5 15.Nc3 Be6 16.Na4 Nd7 17.Rc1 Ba3 18.Rc7 0-0 19.Rxb7? Rac8!|
\begin{figure}[h]
    \bigskip\makediagrams
\end{figure}

Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk df.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setboardfontsize{20pt}`  see section 3.5.1 of the texmate documentation.

Comment: `\bigskip` has no effect on the following code it just makes a big vertical space at that point, like `\vspace`. Also unrelated but do not use `utf8x` with current latex, remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` (which does nothing)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully if you should not follow Ulrike's advice I propose a not so clean code (there is a warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \small invalid in math mode on input line 19.`) using `scalerel` package with option

```
    \begin{center} 
        \scaleobj{2}{\makediagrams}
    \end{center}
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{texmate}
\title{Título}
\date{}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Sección}

Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg .

|1. d4 d5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Bf4 c5 \toD{c5} 4.e3 Nc6 5.c3 Nh5! 6.dxc5 Nxf4 7.exf4 e6 8.b4 Qf6 9.Qd2 a5! 10.b5 Nb8! 11.Qe3 Qe7! 12.c4 Qxc5 13.cxd5 Qxe3+ 14.fxe3 exd5 15.Nc3 Be6 16.Na4 Nd7 17.Rc1 Ba3 18.Rc7 0-0 19.Rxb7? Rac8!|
\begin{center} 
    \scaleobj{2}{\makediagrams}
\end{center}

Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk dfhkh hhg hfggt fgggg btbbt y uhjn kmn Tedg ffhhkhk df.
\end{document}
```

[image]